# IIS7 URL Rewrite Rule not being applied at Website Level

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I'm trying to simulate hosting multiple domains on a single website with IIS7.

I setup a folder structure that has a web_root folder which contains a simple index.html, a web.config, and a folder (connect) holding an asp.net web application. I have attempted to add a url rewrite rule that would take a request to the host localhost.nerdfurio.us and point it into the connect folder (I added localhost.nerdfurio.us to my hosts file as well).

The web.config in web_root looks like this

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="nerdfurious" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost.nerdfurio.us$" />
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/connect/" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="connect/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I type 'localhost.nerdfurio.us' into my browser, I get the contents of the index.html file. If I type localhost.nerdfurio.us/connect into my browser, I get a 404 error listing 'http://localhost.nerdfurio.us:80/connect/connect/' as the requested url. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, the `{PATH_INFO}` rule needed to have a `negate="true"` attribute in the tag. This means when the pattern does not match. Since when I visited the root, "/connect/" was not in the url, and so all conditions were not met to do the rewrite action.